# Fullpage.js plugin: turn background image into a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm quite new to using the fullpage.js pluging and am using it for my portfolio site. The landing page uses the fullpage plugin and shows a couple of images of projects. I would like these background images to be links to different pages. Is there a way to achieve this? I've looked all over the place, but can't seem to find an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us the code on your site that you're working with? Condense it down into a small, complete example, and write it in a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can't turn a background image into a link, but you can turn an element into one with a click handler and you can give that element a background image.

```
<div id="myDiv">
</div>

<style>
  #myDiv {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/xKUoV94.png);
    height: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#myDiv').click(function () {
      window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
    });
  });
</script>
```

http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/NGKaPr

Comment: That's working, thanks! The only thing is that the cursor doesn't change as on regular links. Is there a way to change it to a pointer when hovering over the background image?

Comment: @SofievB Did you miss the `cursor: pointer;` css style? Open my demo link in my answer and you'll see the cursor changes over the image.

Comment: @SofievB Did this work for you? If so, please accept the answer by clicking the little green checkmark ;)